# JAVA and how to execute user-code

Tags: java, runtime, system, conditional-statements

I am building a tool which should do a diagnosis based on some values...
It should be user extensible so hardcoding the conditions isnt a solution...

Suppose that we have a blood test...

example ... WBC , ALDO ...
And i want the user to be able to write somehow scripts

if (WBC.between(4,10) && ALDO.greater(5) || SOMETHINGELESE.isTrue()) ..... diagnosis="MPLAMPLA"...

The problem is
1)Write my parser
2)Or try to find something that executes user conditionals at runtime and customize it..
3)another way

Please help,ideas needed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use scripting (you can use javascript, bsh, groovy, etc). See tutorial [here](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/index.html)
2. Use workflow engine, e.g. [jBPM](http://www.jboss.org/jbpm/)

Comment: Scripting engine is probably the way to go, and certainly the way I'd expose this sort of functionality. This link from my code blog might come in handy also: http://szyzygycode.wordpress.com/2010/03/04/jruby-using-scriptengine-invoking-methods-passing-args/